# How do I only grab one key value pair at a time? PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, object

I'm new to PHP so need some help please.

I seem to have pretty much gotten to almost what I need. However, the code below will do exactly what I want, which is go through each record and grab all key value pairs. Nevertheless, I do not want to out print all remaining $key $val pairs once the condition hits "else". Rather, want I want is to grab the next most key => val pair and repeat until each record is finished.

For Example Right now this code will print out LIST_1, LIST_87 of each record as I want it too. I want it to also grab the next pair of $key => $val only, not the remaining. This is so I may inject each $key => $val pair into a row in mySql.

However right now, it gives me LIST_1, LIST_87 and all remaining $key => $val's.
It looks like this:

```
Record: 0 *************************

LIST_124 => 0.00
GF20121126194243819854000000 => Entry Lvl Lvng Area,Fire Sprinkler,Foyer,Pantry,Volume Ceiling,Walk-in Closet
LIST_125 => 161.14
LIST_122 => 
LIST_123 => 
LIST_126 => 154.18
ROOM_BR2_room_level => 1
VOWAddr => 1
ROOM_PR_room_width => 10.6
GF20121126194243879313000000 => Gate - Manned,Security Patrol
listing_office_phone => (561) 622-5000
GF20121128203448419411000000 => Dining Family,Snack Bar
selling_member_email => jafeldman38@gmail.com
LIST_87 : 2015-01-01T00:01:52
LIST_1 : 20141118214124325535000000

I want it to do this:

Record: 0 *************************

INSERT ---
LIST_87 : 2015-01-01T00:01:52
LIST_1 : 20141118214124325535000000
LIST_124 => 0.00

INSERT ---
LIST_87 : 2015-01-01T00:01:52
LIST_1 : 20141118235552432553500000
LIST_125 => 161.14

INSERT ---
LIST_87 : 2015-01-01T00:01:52
LIST_1 : 20141445635552432553500000
GF20121126194243819854000000 => Entry Lvl Lvng Area,Fire, Sprinkler,Foyer,Pantry,Volume Ceiling,Walk-in Closet
```

CODE:

```
$prop_fields  = array("");
$prop_vals    = array("");
$LIST_1      = "";
$LIST_87     = "";
$count;

class Insert_Data
{

    public function create_insert_sql_from_search(){
      Global $results, $prop_fields, $prop_vals, $LIST_1, $LIST_87, $count ;
      for ($i=0; $i < count($results) ; $i++) { 
          // print "$results[$i]<br/><br/>";
          echo "<br/><br/>Record: $i *************************<br/><br/>";
          $myData = json_decode($results[$i]);
          foreach ($myData as $key => $val) {
              // We append the key and a comma to the end for every key inside the dbkeys array
              if($key == 'LIST_1'){
               $LIST_1 = $val;
               echo "LIST_1 : $LIST_1<br/>";
              }elseif($key == 'LIST_87'){
                $LIST_87 = $val;
                echo "LIST_87 : $LIST_87<br/>";
              }else{
                    echo "$key => $val<br/>";
              }
          }
      } 
    }
}
// create an object
$update = new Insert_Data();

// // show object properties
$update->create_insert_sql_from_search();
// echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: LIST_1, LIST_87 is possible because you have a condition for that, but you have to make a validation that you actually got them. Then retrieve the next key and breaking the for each loop

Answer (score 1):

[Continue();](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php)

You want to use Continue, but see also [Break](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) and accessing array values directly by key.

Comment: I looked into this, I could not make sense of how you want me to use it? Please provide an example in context to this problem so I can better understand.

Comment: I wish this helped but did not work, below I will show you what did work and how I did it with the help of a brilliant Engineer.

Comment: Not so sure about brilliant! I see you figured out how to use the Continue. But your code is a mess, you don't need that loop at all, just access the array keys directly,

Comment: Brilliant is an understatement to say the least. Regardless, I did mention it can be refactored further. However, to your point; we tried accessing the array key directly and it did not work given our problem. Therefore we had to create the two loops which can be done as one when refactoring the code.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are using JSON, why not just retrieve data using the key rather than looping through the JSON array again?

> ```
> $myData = json_decode($results[$i]);
> $List_1 = $myData->List_1;
> echo "List 1 : $List_1";
> $List_87 = $myData->List_87;
> echo "List 87 : $List_87";
> ```

2. I would just go with 1 because it saves you from looping through everything. And if you still want a random pair you can;

> ```
> $randomKey = null;
> while($randomKey != "List_1" || $randomKey != "List_87"){
> $keys = array_keys($myData);
> $randomKey = $keys[ rand(0, count($keys)-1) ];
> }
>
> echo "$randomKey : $myData->$randomKey";
> ```

Another way (your way) would be using Break on the next record when A is true (LIST_1 is found) and B is true (LIST_87 is found) while displaying the record

```
foreach ($myData as $key => $val) {
$a = false,  $b = false;
if($key == 'LIST_1'){
    $LIST_1 = $val;
    $a =  true;
               echo "LIST_1 : $LIST_1<br/>";
}elseif($key == 'LIST_87'){
    $LIST_87 = $val;
    $b = true
    echo "LIST_87 : $LIST_87<br/>";
}else{
    if($a && $b){
    echo "$key => $val<br/>";
    break;
}
}
}
```

Comment: I dont think you are fully understanding what I am trying to accomplish. Your first example is wrong for this solution, and I am not sure what you are trying to do with your second example?

Comment: @VickenCode It grabs a random pair from the json that is not List_1 and not List_87. Yes i clearly understood what you are trying to accomplish and I have given you a different and faster approach

Comment: I really appreciate your help but your method does not work, I have tried in a number of ways. I am confident you are not understanding the problem. This is not the solution. If it is, you certainly did not place it in a context relative to the code I presented to you, for it to be usable.

Comment: @VickenCode I've just tested it on a random JSON and it worked but following your request I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
This the current workable solution and can be refactored further.

require_once('login.php');
$prop_fields  = array("");
$prop_vals    = array("");

class Insert_Data
{

    public function create_insert_sql_from_search(){
      Global $results, $prop_fields, $prop_vals, $LIST_1, $LIST_87;
      for ($i=0; $i < count($results) ; $i++) { 
          // print "$results[$i]<br/><br/>";
          echo "<br/><br/>Record: $i *************************<br/><br/>";
          $myData = json_decode($results[$i]);
          $count = 0;
          $LIST_1      = "";
          $LIST_87     = "";
          $elements    = array();
          // iterate over myData to extract LIST_1 AND LIST_87 vals
          foreach ($myData as $key => $val) {
              // We append the key and a comma to the end for every key inside the dbkeys array
              if($key == 'LIST_1') {
                $LIST_1 = $val;
                // echo "$key : $LIST_1 <br/>";
              } elseif($key == 'LIST_87'){
                $LIST_87 = $val;
                // echo "$key : $LIST_87 <br/>";
              } else {
                continue;
              }
          }
          // iterate over myData to extract everything else
          foreach ($myData as $key => $val) {
              // We append the key and a comma to the end for every key inside the dbkeys array
              if (($key == 'LIST_1') || ($key == 'LIST_87')) {
                continue;
              } else {
                // add to our array 
                array_push($elements, array($LIST_1, $key, $val, $LIST_87));
              }
          }
          // done 
          // display our results
          //print_r($elements);

          foreach ($elements as $key => $value) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO [TABLE] (`LIST_1`, `KEY`, `VALUE`, 'LIST_87') VALUES ({$elements[$key][0]}, {$elements[$key][1]}, {$elements[$key][2]}, {$elements[$key][3]});";
            print_r($query); echo "<br>";  
          }

       } // $conn->close();
    }
}
// create an object
$update = new Insert_Data();

// // show object properties
$update->create_insert_sql_from_search();
// echo "</pre>";
```